# Is the dexterity bonus limited by armor type?

Tags: adnd-1e

Is the dexterity bonus in the AD&D game limited by armor type?

For example, take a fighter with a DEX of 18 in full plate armor. Does he/she get the full -4 to reflex?

Comment: There is no reflex save in AD&D, so I think you may be confused about what game you're asking about.

Comment: I started to go to my physical books for the first time in a long time, then realized this question is 1e and my books are 2e. :P

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're not just confused and are really talking about AD&D First Edition, no, the armor does not affect the *Reaction/Attacking Adjustment* or the *Defensive Adjustment*.  In fact, right under the Dexterity table it has an explicit example...

> *Defensive Adjustment* refers to the penalty or bonus applicable to a
>   character’s saving throws against certain forms of attack (such as fire ball,
>   lightning bolts, etc.) due to dodging ability. It also applies to the
>   character‘s parrying and/or dodging ability in missile or melee combat; in
>   this case the penalty subtracts from the armor class (q.v.) of the character,
>   making him or her easier to hit, while the bonus adds to the defensive
>   value of the character’s armor class, making him or her harder to hit. For
>   example, a character with plate mail and shield is normally treated as
>   armor class 2; if the character has 3 dexterity, there is a +4 penalty, so the
>   armor class changes to 6 (2 + 4). However, if the same character has a
>   dexterity of 18, there is a bonus of -4, so armor class changes from 2 to a -2
>   (2 + -4 = 1, 0, -1, -2).